# Swift, Collection View: Section Headers not shown

Tags: swift, macos, collections, header, nscollectionview

I'm trying to program a NSCollectionView in Swift, MacOS. It's working well, with one exception. The section headers won't appear. Where they should appear is just empty space. The last `collectionView` function in the code below, which should be called each time a header is drawn, gets never ever called. Instead, it throws this warning:

> Instance method 'collectionView(*:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:at:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'collectionView(*:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:at:)' of protocol 'NSCollectionViewDataSource'

Does anybody know what I did wrong? How can I get the program to call the supplementary-view-collectionView-function?

Best!

```
extension FacetWindow: NSCollectionViewDataSource{
        func numberOfSections(in collectionView: NSCollectionView) -> Int {
        return facets.count // how many sections?
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return facets.facets[section].facetContent.count //how many items in section?
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {
        let item = collectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "FacetsWindowCollectionViewItem"), for: indexPath)
        guard let collectionViewItem = item as? FacetsWindowCollectionViewItem else {return item}
        collectionViewItem.textField?.stringValue = facets[indexPath[0], indexPath[1]]
        print("facet" , facets[indexPath[0], indexPath[1]])
        return item
    }

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSView {
        //this function never gets called!!!
        let view = collectionView.makeSupplementaryView(ofKind: NSCollectionView.SupplementaryElementKind.sectionHeader, withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "FacetsWindowCollectionViewHeader"), for: indexPath) as! FacetsWindowCollectionViewHeader
        view.FacetsWindowCollectionViewHeaderLabel.stringValue = facets[indexPath[0]]
        return view
        }

}
```

Comment: It's hard to see what you are doing wrong because you don't explain your variables.  What is FacetsWindowCollectionViewHeader, and how is it created?  What is facets?  There are no explanations.

Comment: Did you check the documentation of `collectionView(_:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:at:)`? Is your declaration identical?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, I found the answer!

This code:

collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSView

was never called, because the system didn't know it anymore. It was old code that I copypasted from a code sample. Retyped it manually and the XCode made the right suggestions.